# Rails routes vs Angular2 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, routes

I'm using Angular2 inside a rails application. My entry point is my index.html that is located in my public folder.
What I need is to call this index.html with an id (representing the entity that called it) like this index/id=2.
But whenever I issue such a call, I get an error, because my rails application first intercepts the call and tries to resolve this route which of course doesn't  exist on my rails route. Is there a way to solve this issue, or should I move my index under a rails view  ?

Comment: Hey did you manage ton find any solution for this?